How can I add a new Flatpak app to the LXDE menu?
I have downloaded a couple of flatpaks after installing and launch them from CLI, for example
flatpak run com.spotify.Client 

works fine.
However flatpaks don't seem to add icons to the LXDE app menu as native ones do.
I have copied the .desktop file from:
~/.local/share/flatpak/app/com.spotify.Client/x86_64/stable/active/files/share/applications/com.spotify.Client.desktop

To:
/usr/share/applications

Where all native .desktop files also reside. However the LXDE menu still does not pick my flatpaks up.
I have also tried to edit lxde-application.menu, by adding for example a section for 'Audio' (as one of the categories of Spotify is Audio) but it simply replicated the AudioVisual category with just Pulse Audio in (presumably because pulseaudio is also in the Audio category).
I am at a loss as to how to get these flatpaks showing as icons in the menu, any help would be greatly appreciated

Possibly relevant: this RPi forum thread explains that flatpaks, snaps and the startlxde script currently set XDG_DATA_DIRS in a way that causes the latter to ignore the former (debian bug report, ubuntu bug report). The thread also describes a workaround for that, which I haven't tested (hence posted as comment instead of answer, also because this technically answers a different question).

I have just tried the solution and it does indeed add all flatpak apps to the menu, but I have a hunch that this could mean that if any lxde script tries to change its XDG_DATA_DIRS, this desktop.config then setting masks out that again. So then one would have to comment out that line, log out/log in, see the changes to the XDG_DATA_DIRS setting, add those to the desktop.config line, and log out/log in again. Presumably that happens less often than that one adds/removes flatpak apps though.

I have solved myself, for anyone else reading my solution might be useful - using the flatpak .desktop was a red herring, the solution is to roll your own, instructions below.
cd into your applications folder:
cd /usr/share/applications/
Create a new blank .desktop file:
sudo touch spotify.desktop

open with root privelages in Mousepad/Leafpad or similar:
sudo mousepad spotify.desktop

Copy and paste in the following. Note the Icon line refrences the .svg file installed with the flatpak but you can reference something else if you like, just change the file path:

[Desktop Entry] Type=Application Terminal=false Name=Spotify
Icon=Icon=/home//.local/share/flatpak/app/com.spotify.Client/current/active/files/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/com.spotify.Client.svg
Exec=flatpak run com.spotify.Client Type-Application Categories
AudioVideo;

Note also the Categories line; I have simply made Spotify an AudioVideo category to go in the existing 'Sound and Video' menu item but you could make it 'Audio' Category if you wished for example, just add a new 'Audio' category in lxde-applications.menu:
/etc/xdg/menus

